# Unsymmetrical result for an interpolation of two coordinate vectors and one symmetrical assigned value vector

Tags: matlab, plot, interpolation

I have two coordinate vectors x what is the vector in x-direction and y what is the vector in y-direction and a corresponding z value vector what is called "z".
I now want to interpolate this non-uniform data to a very fine uniform coordinates grid.
But somehow the result is not symmetrical although the actual z values are symmetrical:
[See output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14Khv.jpg).
Anybody does how to solve this simple issue?
Here is my code:

```
  x = [0;0;0;0;0;50;50;50;50;50;95;95;95;95;95;100;100;100;100;100;150;150;150;150;150];
  y = [0;250;500;750;1000;0;250;500;750;1000;0;250;500;750;1000;0;250;500;750;1000;0;250;500;750;1000];

  XspanVector = 1:1:150;
  YspanVector = 1:1:1000;

  [xx,yy] = meshgrid(obsXspanVector,obsYspanVector);

  z = [2000 3000 15165 3000 2000 2000 3000 35750519 3000 2000 2000 3000 113059 3000 2000 2000 3000 109117 3000 2000 2000 3000 36863 3000 2000];

  % Interpolate to grid
  zz = griddata(x,y,z',xx,yy,'linear');

  % Plot
  contourf(xx,yy,10.*log10(zz),'LineColor','none');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you have a regular `[5 x 5]` grid so instead of `griddata` you need to use [`interp2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html) or [`griddedInterpolant`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddedinterpolant.html).

```
xi = reshape(xObsG,5,5);
yi = reshape(yObsG,5,5);
zi = reshape(obsMaxIntInterpFlyoverSum,5,5);
z  = interp2(xi,yi,zi,xxObsG,yyObsG);

contourf(xxObsG,yyObsG,10.*log10(z),'LineColor','none');
```

[image: Symmetric]